# zipcode validation

Tags: validation

Does salesforce provide a feature using which we can validate that the value user has inputted in an input text for zipcode is valid US zipcode value ? How can we validate that user entered valid US zip code ?

Comment: Are you doing this programmatically or through the declarative means?

Comment: i would like to do it declaratively, but i think i will have to use programattic way by calling a web service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salesforce does not provide this functionality.  If you want to validate the format, you could use a validation rule with a regex to test the format of the inputted value.  If you actually want to validate that it is a legitimate postal code, there are several apps on the App exchange that do this, along with other types of address validation.

Comment: what are the pros and cons of using an app exchange app vs. any free third party web service that can do the validation.

Comment: With an appexchange app, you're usually getting more address verification than just the ZIP, and you should be getting some support. Using a free third party web service would require custom Apex and perhaps VF code to make the call-out and handle the results. You could look at the Salesforce Foundation Nonprofit Starter Pack code for some examples; they support Google, SmartyStreets and Cicero: https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus

Comment: @thomasTaylor is correct.  It depends on whether you want to be in the business of managing the custom code, or leverage a commercial product.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the above, there are the following resources

- [Useful Validation Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_useful_validation_formulas.pdf) (SFDC Doc - US and Canadian postal codes)
- [Validating zipcode against table of valid zipcodes](http://www.salesforcetutorial.com/using-vlookup-enforces-data-consistency/) (uses VLOOKUP function)

Answer (score 2):

Use a validation rule.  The following will work on accounts:

AND(
OR(BillingCountry = "USA", BillingCountry = "US", BillingCountry = "United States"),
NOT(REGEX(BillingPostalCode, "\d{5}(-\d{4})?"))
)

Comment: i think this will not check weather it is a  legitimate postal code, while this can do format check.

Comment: That is correct, the above formula will validate format only.  It will not check for valid United States postal code.  As @JimRae alluded to, there are apps on the app exchange that handle checking for valid postal codes.

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw out some ideas to give you something to think about.  You could create a new object called States and Zip codes so `USZip_Codes__c`.  And in this `USZip_Codes__c` object you would need to maintain the unique combination of each state, county, and zip code.. Then you will need to create a trigger/class to check the object combination to the record that you inserting/updating.

This may not be a solution that is realistic to you, and may question the proper techniques,  but it is possible.  As other members said there may be solutions on the app exchange.